Get events from external api to outlook calendar
Is it possible to fetch events from external api to Outlook calendar? I need onky to get events, no need to add, modify or delete events.
One way could be to create an .ics file on the server and share it from the api(?).
I'm running the api on an iis-server. Backend technologies are nodejs and express. I'm using iisnode to run the nodejs app on the iis server.
